# How to generate unique letters and append them to a string in python?

Tags: python, string, random, append

I am currently writing a code where the user needs to enter an input string minimum of 4 to 12 letters, must not contain any numbers and must be unique. Once all three conditions are passed, the program will generate a set of letters that will include the input string and other unique letters to form double the length of the input string. I have cleared all three conditions but am unsure how to generate unique letters and append them to the input string.

```
def main2():
    player_input = input("Enter target letters: ").upper() 
    if  4 <= len(player_input) < 12 \
        and len(set(player_input)) == len(player_input) \
             and player_input.isalpha():
                  print(player_input)
    
    elif not 4 <= len(player_input) < 12:
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    elif len(set(player_input)) != len(player_input):
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    elif not player_input.isalpha():
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    else:
         print(player_input)        
main2()
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provided an example input and an example of the desired result.

You could utilize the `choice` function from `random` library to pick a random value. And the `string` library for a quick list of letters for this task. Then use a `while` loop to search for unique letters.

```
import random
import string

player_input = 'WORD'
letters = string.ascii_uppercase  # Letters of the alphabet

result = player_input
while len(result) < len(player_input) * 2:  # Add letter until equal length
    ltr = random.choice(letters)
    if ltr not in player_input:  # Check that random letter is unique.
        result += ltr
```

Example result:

> WORDZLNX

I would also recommend using a `while` loop for you criteria checks of `player_input`.

Answer (score 0):

append python function would be your best bet. Something like this:
https://www.javatpoint.com/python-program-to-generate-a-random-string
As for the length of the numbers added to the end of the users input, you'll have to make a function that takes the length of the users input and multiplies it by two to get you to your required length.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended your code to do this:

```py
from random import randint

def main2():
    player_input = input("Enter target letters: ").upper()
    if  4 <= len(player_input) < 12 \
        and len(set(player_input)) == len(player_input) \
             and player_input.isalpha():

                  letters = {chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)}
                  lettersNotInInput = list(letters - set(player_input))
                  for i in range(len(player_input)):
                      newLetter = lettersNotInInput.pop(randint(0, len(lettersNotInInput)))
                      player_input += newLetter
                  print(player_input)

    elif not 4 <= len(player_input) < 12:
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    elif len(set(player_input)) != len(player_input):
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    elif not player_input.isalpha():
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")
    else:
         print(player_input)
main2()
```

How it works:

- Creates a set of letters from "A" to "Z" (uses ascii codes so I didn't have to hard code the alphabet
- Performs a set subtraction to remove letters already in the input from the set producing the list `lettersNotInInput`
- It then loops for the length of the `player_input` effectively doubling the length
- Pops a random letter from the list (ensuring it can only be selected once) and adds it to the `player_input`

Answer (score 0):

Well first I think that your code could be cleaned up a lot by just using a regular expression to do the check as opposed to stacked if/elifs.

Now are these appended letters unique to entire string? or just this appended sub-string? My general recommendation, and there may be better ways to do this, is to generate a list of random unique numbers (there are lots of references to do this online) that is bounded from 97-122, and once you're done convert these numbers into characters with "chr()" - casting the numbers back to characters. Then convert this character list to a string using ".join", and you can then append this string to your existing string that was read in. Again there are likely better/more efficient ways to do this, so if your application needs to be heavily optimized maybe try something else.

```
from random import random, choice, sample
import re

string_req = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z]{4,12}$') 
in_str = input("Enter your string: ")
match = string_req.match(in_str)
if match:
    match_str = match.group()
    unique_list = sample(range(97, 122), len(match_str))
    # Turn all numbers back into characters
    unique_str = "".join([chr(c) for c in unique_list])
    # Randomally capitalize some so that capitals are factored in
    out_str = match_str + "".join((choice((str.upper, str.lower))(c) for c in unique_str)))
else:
    print('No match')
```

Also note - this code only checks that the letters within the appended section are unique -  if you want it the other way, where the values are unique to the entire string, then you will need to generate a list of ints from the input string, and include that in the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
import string

def main2():
    player_input = input("Enter target letters: ").upper()

    playerlen=len(player_input) # Length of the player_input
    playersetlen=len(set(player_input)) # Length of set
    isalfa=player_input.isalpha() # True/False result of isalpha()

    if  4 <= playerlen < 12 and playersetlen == playerlen and isalfa:
        print(player_input+"".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase,k=playerlen)))

    elif playerlen<4 or playerlen > 12 or playersetlen != playerlen or isalfa==False:
         print(f"Must be unique characters from and of length 4 to 12")

    else:
         print(player_input)
main2()
```

Main this is:

```
"".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase,k=playerlen))
```

This is basically choosing 5 uppercase character from [A-Z] and joining those characters.

Other changes in your code is just to make code simpler and faster. You are doing multiple time same things, so I have changed those to some variables and now if we have to use that function then we can just use those assigned variables. And I have delete other `elif` conditions and add all conditions in just one, you are just printing same things in all of the conditions, so I did this. And now not sure when that `else` condition will occur but I haven't changed anything of `else` condition. But I believe, that `elif` can be replaced by `else` condition only.